# how to get the value from DB sql then put it in Switch () with controller

Tags: flutter

TextField, which is a Material Design text field that can be controlled with TextEditingController. how for type instead of Text, let's say for example like Switch, it's type bool, is it also using TextEditingController ??

Example :
(String) Text : `final TextEditingController _valuetext = TextEditingController();`
(bool) Switch Selection : ??

please Help :)

Comment: could not understand what you're looking for, can you explain a bit?

Comment: I just edit, could you please explain

Comment: See this implementation of switch in flutter, and let me know what you don't understand! https://dev.to/maadhav_sharma/a-short-tutorial-on-how-to-develop-a-switch-button-in-flutter-52mp#:~:text=Flutter%20Switch%20is%20used%20to,off%2C%20onChanged%20property%20returns%20false.